# Unsupervised raster classification using GDAL

Tags: arcpy, raster, gdal, classification, digital-image-processing

Is there an equivalent in GDAL to the Arcpy ISO data unsupervised classification tool, or a series of methods using GDAL/python that can accomplish this?

Comment: try this http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/Projects/ISODATA/ or the kMean from OTB (but the latter is not exactly the same as ISODATA).

Comment: The Python package [pyradar](https://github.com/PyRadar/pyradar) includes an [ISOdata classifier in Python](https://github.com/PyRadar/pyradar/blob/master/pyradar/classifiers/isodata.py). GDAL, as with most Python scripts, is used to import and export your image data to/from numpy arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, both of those look like good possibilities.

Answer (score 8):

[Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) has some excellent unsupervised classification/clustering algorithms. The [batched K-means algorithm](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html) works quickly with large datasets.

Here is an example using the KEA file format. You will have to modify this slightly to work with whatever raster format you use.

```
import rsgislib
from rsgislib import imageutils
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy
import glob
import sys
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans

# Search current directory for KEA rasters
InputImages = glob.glob('*.kea')

# Define the number of spectral classes
SpectralClasses = 6

# Define format and datatype of output raster
gdalformat = 'KEA'
gdaldatatype = gdal.GDT_Byte

# Define the classifier
clf = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=SpectralClasses, init='k-means++', max_iter=10, batch_size=10000, verbose=0, compute_labels=True, random_state=None, tol=0.0, max_no_improvement=100, init_size=2000, n_init=10, reassignment_ratio=0.05)

# Terminate the script if the returned list is empty
if not InputImages:
  sys.exit("Error: No input images provided.")

for Raster in sorted(InputImages):
    OutImage = Raster.replace('.kea','_Classified.kea')

    print("Reading " + Raster)
    Image = gdal.Open(Raster, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

    # Set up empty list to hold data
    TestData = []

    # Read data from each band
    for band in range(Image.RasterCount):
        band += 1

        B = Image.GetRasterBand(band)

        Array = B.ReadAsArray()

        # Get shape of array
        Shape = numpy.ma.shape(Array)

        # Flatten to 1D array
        Array = Array.flatten()

        TestData.append(Array)

        del Array

    TestData = numpy.array(TestData, dtype=numpy.dtype('float32')) # Convert to float to prevent sklearn error/warning message 
    TestData = numpy.transpose(TestData)

    print("Performing K-means classification...")
    clf.fit(TestData, y=None)
    predictedClass = clf.predict(TestData)

    del TestData

    predictedClass = predictedClass + 1 #Add 1 to exclude zeros in output raster
    predictedClass = numpy.reshape(predictedClass, Shape) # Reshape the numpy array to match the original image

    # Create an output raster the same size as the input image
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(gdalformat)
    metadata = driver.GetMetadata()
    output = driver.Create(OutImage, Image.RasterXSize, Image.RasterYSize, 1, gdaldatatype)

    # Create projection info for the output raster
    output.SetProjection(Image.GetProjectionRef())
    output.SetGeoTransform(Image.GetGeoTransform()) 

    # Write classification to band 1
    output_band = output.GetRasterBand(1)
    output_band.WriteArray(predictedClass)

    # Close datasets
    output_band = None
    output = None
    Image = None
    del predictedClass

    # Build image overviews
    imageutils.popImageStats(OutImage, True, 0, True)
    print("Done." + '\n')

print("All images processed.")
```

You will also want to create a binary mask image so you can clip/remove nodata regions from the output. I have skipped this step for brevity.

If you don't want to code all of this yourself through Python, you can undertake the k-means and ISOdata classifications using [RSGISLib](http://www.rsgislib.org/). Type "rsgiscmd -h classification" in the terminal for a list of options.

Answer (score 2):

Brian, you could ask this question at http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/gdal-dev/ and perhaps get a more specific target audience.  Also, while not providing a GDAL way to accomplishment this page (http://www.yale.edu/ceo/Projects/swap/landcover/Unsupervised_classification.htm) gives a nice summary of the differences between KMEANS and ISO DATA perhaps providing some insight into how you might write a custom function similar to http://geoexamples.blogspot.com/2012/02/raster-classification-with-gdal-python.html

Best, 
Derek